# how to make SliverAppBar color the background

Tags: flutter

I'm building a Flutter app and when I try to use `SliverAppBar` it does not apply background color to all screen's top, like in the image.

[image]

The edges of the clock and network are not in blue.

What am I missing in my code?

```
return SliverAppBar(
      pinned: widget.isPinAppBar,
      snap: false,
      floating: false,
      titleSpacing: 0,
      elevation: 0,
      forceElevated: true,
      backgroundColor: HexColor('2400ff'),
          // Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background.withOpacity(config.opacity),
      title: PreviewOverlay(
          index: 0,
          config: logoConfig as Map<String, dynamic>?,
          builder: (value) {
            final appModel = Provider.of<AppModel>(context, listen: true);
            return Selector<CartModel, int>(
              selector: (_, cartModel) => cartModel.totalCartQuantity,
              builder: (context, totalCart, child) {
                return Selector<NotificationModel, int>(
                  selector: (context, notificationModel) =>
                      notificationModel.unreadCount,
                  builder: (context, unreadCount, child) {
                    return Logo(
                      config: config,
                      logo: appModel.themeConfig.logo,
                      notificationCount: unreadCount,
                      totalCart: totalCart,
                      onSearch: () {
                        FluxNavigate.pushNamed(RouteList.homeSearch);
                      },
                      onCheckout: () {
                        FluxNavigate.pushNamed(RouteList.cart);
                      },
                      onTapNotifications: () {
                        FluxNavigate.pushNamed(RouteList.notify);
                      },
                      onTapDrawerMenu: () =>
                          NavigateTools.onTapOpenDrawerMenu(context),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            );
          }),
    );
```

Comment: Are you using a SliverSafeArea / SafeArea above your SliverAppBar? if so, remove it or add top: false

Answer (score 2):

I guess your code having no issues, unfortunately i couldn't test your exact code because it's not complete code.

However I guess you are using SafeArea somewhere opove your code, try to remove it and test it again.

I hope it will solve your issue,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside your `void main(){}` in `main.dart`

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: HexColor('2400ff'),
  ));
```